# Can not connect to MongoDB via the Python Web Framework Bottle

Tags: mongodb, bottle

I am not able to connect through bottle with my MongoDB. The usual way works fine:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('....uri_string....')

db = client.myCluster

collection = db.collection

collection.insert_one({'key': 'value'})
```

But if I try it this way, I am not able to connect.

```
from bottle import Bottle
from bottle.ext.mongo import MongoPlugin

app = Bottle()

database_name = 'myCluster'
db_uri = '....uri_string....'

db_plugin = MongoPlugin(uri=db_uri, db=database_name)

app.install(db_plugin)

@app.route('/')
def index(mongodb):
    mongodb['collection'].insert({'key': 'value'})
    mongodb['collection'].insert({'key': 'value2'})
    return 'Inserted Data'

app.run(debug=True, reloader=True)
```

I get the error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

I am using the free MongoDB Cloud.